# Is it legal to make wine on my farm?

Tags: wine

Is it illegal to make wine on my farm, do I need a license to make wine? I have searched the internet but can only find answers concerning beer making.

Comment: It might matter where you are.

Comment: There are lots of wine making kits available. The answer may depend on whether you want to sell what you make.

Comment: Which country are you residing in?

Comment: I don't think it's illegal anywhere to make wine unless you are in Saudi Arabia or some other Muslim country. If you are in the USA, you can make up to 200 gallons a year for you family. If you want to sell it, then that is where the roadblocks come in.

Comment: @farmersteve Good answer. Perhaps you should post it as one.

Comment: @EricShain I will if he ever comes back and tells us where he is from.